# Convert carriage return (\r) to actual overwrite

Tags: string, bash, formatting, carriage-return

## Questions

Is there a way to convert the carriage returns to actual overwrite in a string so that `000000000000\r1010` is transformed to `101000000000`?

## Context

### 1. Initial objective:

Having a number `x` (between 0 and 255) in base 10, I want to convert this number in base 2, add trailing zeros to get a 12-digits long binary representation, generate 12 different numbers (each of them made of the last `n` digits in base 2, with `n` between 1 and 12) and print the base 10 representation of these 12 numbers.

### 2. Example:

1. With `x = 10`
2. Base 2 is `1010`
3. With trailing zeros `101000000000`
4. Extract the 12 "leading" numbers: `1`, `10`, `101`, `1010`, `10100`, `101000`, ...
5. Convert to base 10: `1`, `2`, `5`, `10`, `20`, `40`, ...

### 3. What I have done (it does not work):

```
x=10
x_base2="$(echo "obase=2;ibase=10;${x}" | bc)"
x_base2_padded="$(printf '%012d\r%s' 0 "${x_base2}")"
for i in {1..12}
do
    t=$(echo ${x_base2_padded:0:${i}})
    echo "obase=10;ibase=2;${t}" | bc
done
```

### 4. Why it does not work

Because the variable `x_base2_padded` contains the whole sequence `000000000000\r1010`. This can be confirmed using `hexdump` for instance. In the for loop, when I extract the first 12 characters, I only get zeros.

### 5. Alternatives

I know I can find alternative by literally adding zeros to the variable as follow:

```
x_base2=1010
x_base2_padded="$(printf '%s%0.*d' "${x_base2}" $((12-${#x_base2})) 0)"
```

Or by padding with zeros using `printf` and `rev`

```
x_base2=1010
x_base2_padded="$(printf '%012s' "$(printf "${x_base2}" | rev)" | rev)"
```

Although these alternatives solve my problem now and let me continue my work, it does not really answer my question.

## Related issue

The same problem may be observed in different contexts. For instance if one tries to concatenate multiple strings containing carriage returns. The result may be hard to predict.

```
str=$'bar\rfoo'
echo "${str}"
echo "${str}${str}"
echo "${str}${str}${str}"
echo "${str}${str}${str}${str}"
echo "${str}${str}${str}${str}${str}"
```

The first `echo` will output `foo`. Although you might expect the other `echo` to output `foofoofoo...`, they all output `foobar`.

Comment: The question is really just about how to store the actual result of what would be actually printed with a string containing a carriage return. The section "initial objective" is to prevent comments asking "what do you really want to do?". I gave quite some context indeed, to make sure it is clear for everyone. The section "Question" seems pretty clear to me that this is the question I am really asking, sorry if too much details can be confusing.

Comment: @alecxs Thanks. But if you extract the first 12 characters, you will only get zeros `echo -e ${x:0:12}`. Even if you store in a variable in between, the `\r` is still there.

Comment: @Slagt Thanks for confirming this. Maybe once you accepted an answer, you could boil the question down to "`Convert \r to actual overwrite`" or something like that. Never seen such a nicely written question like yours -- lets make it even nicer once the danger of "`closed as XY problem`" is gone :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following function `overwrite` transforms its argument such that after each carriage return `\r` the beginning of the string is actually overwritten:

```
overwrite() {
    local segment result=
    while IFS= read -rd $'\r' segment; do
       result="$segment${result:${#segment}}"
    done < <(printf '%s\r' "$@")
    printf %s "$result"
}
```

#### Example

```
$ overwrite $'abcdef\r0123\rxy'
xy23ef
```

Note that the printed string is actually `xy23ef`, unlike `echo $'abcdef\r0123\rxy'` which only *seems* to print the same string, but still prints `\r` which is then interpreted by your terminal such that the result *looks* the same. You can confirm this with `hexdump`:

```
$ echo $'abcdef\r0123\rxy' | hexdump -c
0000000   a   b   c   d   e   f  \r   0   1   2   3  \r   x   y  \n
000000f
$ overwrite $'abcdef\r0123\rxy' | hexdump -c
0000000   x   y   2   3   e   f
0000006
```

The function `overwrite` also supports overwriting by arguments instead of `\r`-delimited segments:

```
$ overwrite abcdef 0123 xy
xy23ef
```

To convert variables in-place, use a subshell: `myvar=$(overwrite "$myvar")`

Comment: Works perfectly, with multiple `\r` even though I didn't specifically ask for it. This is also the fastest execution suggested so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With awk, you'd set the field delimiter to `\r` and iterate through fields printing only the visible portions of them.

```
awk -F'\r' '{
  offset = 1
  for (i=NF; i>0; i--) {
    if (offset <= length($i)) {
      printf "%s", substr($i, offset)
      offset = length($i) + 1
    }
  }
  print ""
}'
```

This is indeed too long to put into a command substitution. So you better wrap this in a function, and pipe the lines to be resolved to that.

Comment: Same comment as the one I made for the accepted answer. Working like a charm, also with multiple `\r` which was not specifically asked, but is definitely a plus. It is slightly slower than accepted answer though (+10%). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the specific question, how to convert `000000000000\r1010` to `101000000000`, refer to [Socowi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62218374/3266847).

However, I wouldn't introduce the carriage return in the first place and solve the problem like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

x=$1

# Start with 12 zeroes
var='000000000000'

# Convert input to binary
binary=$(bc <<< "obase = 2; $x")

# Rightpad with zeroes: ${#binary} is the number of characters in $binary,
# and ${var:x} removes the first x characters from $var
var=$binary${var:${#binary}}

# Print 12 substrings, convert to decimal: ${var:0:i} extracts the first
# i characters from $var, and $((x#$var)) interprets $var in base x
for ((i = 1; i <= ${#var}; ++i)); do
    echo "$((2#${var:0:i}))"
done
```

Comment: @alecxs I had an (incorrect) answer for it, and fixing it would have made it the same as Socowi's answer, so I refer to that answer instead. I think the approach is flawed in the first place, so I focus on  a solution for the overarching problem here instead.