# In bash, can I save the progress meter and its format to a variable for a cURL request?

Tags: bash, curl

I currently have:

```
result=$(curl "https://www.google.com" 2>&1 > /dev/null)
```

where

```
echo $result
```

gives us:

```
100 11972 0 11972 0 0 67258 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 67258t Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
```

The format appears to have been crushed into a single string. Is there a way to retain the original format? Which looks like a table:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  11972 0 11972 0 0 67258 0   9775   --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  67258
```

Comment: Curl uses a carriage return character for overwriting the progress bar, are you looking for sth like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217137/convert-carriage-return-r-to-actual-overwrite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can do something like this :

1. capture curl statistics output to a file
2. read the file into an array variable (line by line)

   ```
   $ curl https://www.google.com 2>&1 > /dev/null | tee my_outfile
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100 14569    0 14569    0     0  62527      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 62260
    $ 
    $ 
    $ cat my_outfile
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100 14569    0 14569    0     0  62527      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 62260

    $ IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a result_array < my_outfile
    $ 
    $ echo "${result_array[0]}"
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
    $ 
    $ echo "${result_array[1]}"
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    $ 
    $ echo "${result_array[2]}"
    100 14554    0 14554    0     0  39765      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 39656
   ```

Comment: Although the question is about Bash , it worth mention that your code works natively in Zsh

Comment: Actually, no, because arrays are indexed in zsh from1 and not from 0.

Comment: just to clarify, in my answer im is using a Bash shell. if i use Zsh, then the expression in the question is working, and the var “result“ contains the expected results.

Comment: What zsh do you have? When I run it on mine, already the `read` fails with _bad option: -a_, because the zsh _read_ does not  have `-a`. According to the man page, it has `-rszpqAclneE` and (with arguments) `-T`, `-K`, `-D` and `-U`. I can use `-A` instead, but then, `echo "${result_array[0]}"` does not work (`echo $result_array[1]` would do). What does a `echo $ZSH_VERSION` show you when you are on zsh?

Comment: i meant that your code in the question : result=$( curl .....) is work in zsh